# MySQL ensuring that is_free_lock is always exclusive

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mutex, mutual-exclusion

I'm using mysql get_lock to ensure mutual exclusion between multiple instances of php scripts that I am running for the same lines of code. I need to ensure that two simultaneous executions of the is_free_lock will not yield 0, in which case I will end up locking by both instances of the script and then execute that code twice. Please help.

```
if($lock->isLockFree()) {
    // lock

    // release lock
} else {
    // trigger already locked error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use [IS_FREE_LOCK(str)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_is-free-lock). You just should use [GET_LOCK(str,timeout)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock) and check if it returns 1 (success, lock gained) or 0 (fail, lock already gained). So your code should look like this:

```
// try to lock
if($lock->getLock()) {
    // locked

    // release lock
    $lock->releaseLock();
} else {
    // trigger already locked error
}
```

Where `getLock()` should use [GET_LOCK(str,timeout)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock)

BTW if you use php you may want to try my [ninja-mutex](https://github.com/arvenil/ninja-mutex) library for locking.